# Does Kestel (.NET Core 3.1) support md5RSA certificates?

Tags: ssl, .net-core, certificate, .net-core-3.1

I have been trying to get a simple HTTPS secured Kestrel service running which validates clients using an installed self-signed root certificate (from a 3rd party). I am struggling to find what is specifically is wrong with the client certificate and why the service is bouncing the connection. Could someone answer categorically that Kestrel in .NET Core 3.1 on a linux box running OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017 no long accepts root certs which have a signature algorithm of md5RSA ?
[image]

I have been unable to fuind any way to find anything more specific from Kestrel.

I added the following to the program.cs to try to help:

```
    private static bool ClientCertificateValidation(X509Certificate2 clientCertificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            int certNumber = 0;
            foreach (X509ChainElement element in chain.ChainElements)
            {
                certNumber++;
                var errors = element.ChainElementStatus;
                List<string> errorList = new List<string>();
                foreach(var cError in errors)
                {
                    errorList.Add(cError.StatusInformation);
                }
                sb.AppendLine("Certificate #" + certNumber + ": (" + string.Join(",", errorList.ToArray())  + ")");
                sb.AppendLine("  Subject: " + element.Certificate.Subject);
                sb.AppendLine("  Issuer: " + element.Certificate.Issuer);
                sb.AppendLine("  Serial #: " + element.Certificate.SerialNumber);
                sb.AppendLine("  Thumbprint: " + element.Certificate.Thumbprint);
                sb.AppendLine("  Valid Dates: " + element.Certificate.NotBefore.ToString() + " to " + element.Certificate.NotAfter.ToString());
                sb.AppendLine("  Signature Algorithm: " + element.Certificate.SignatureAlgorithm.FriendlyName);
                sb.AppendLine("  Version: " + element.Certificate.Version);
                sb.AppendLine("  Encoded Certificate: " + Convert.ToBase64String(element.Certificate.Export(X509ContentType.Cert)));
            }

            Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());

                if (sslPolicyErrors.HasFlag(SslPolicyErrors.None))
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"***************** NO POLICY ERRORS! **********************");
                return true;
            }
            return false;    
        }
```

Calling it via:

```
 public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseSerilog()
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                webBuilder.ConfigureKestrel(options =>
                {
                    options.ConfigureHttpsDefaults(
                        httpsOptions =>
                        {
                            httpsOptions.ClientCertificateMode = ClientCertificateMode.RequireCertificate;
                            httpsOptions.SslProtocols = SslProtocols.Tls12;
                            httpsOptions.ClientCertificateValidation =ClientCertificateValidation;
                        });
                });
            });
```

But truly "Certificate signature failure" gives me little to go on. Having run openssl verify - the result is OK....So what is Kestrel doing?

Thanks in advance

**UPDATE:**

The self signed (3rd party) certificate is installed on the server to validate the 3rd party's clients. The command mentioned does return an error though as the cert was supplied by a 3rd party I am unsure what the problem with it is?

[image: check_ss_sig]

Comment: Although you make it impossible to tell, that cert _might_ be the root i.e. selfsigned. If so, `openssl verify` by default doesn't check its signature; use `openssl verify -check_ss_sig`

Comment: Updated my original post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so both dotnet and openssl agree the signature is invalid. Although I don't see a practical way to reproduce this, 'unknown digest' (instead of 'bad padding' or 'out of range') suggests the signature was in fact created by the issuer (i.e. not corrupted data or signature, or wrong key) but the signer did it wrong. Try the following procedure (I used my own cert since yours is too private for anybody to see):

```
$ openssl req -newkey rsa:1024 -keyout 70348834.key -nodes -x509 -md5 -subj /CN=70348834 -out 70348834.crt
Generating a RSA private key
.....+++++
....+++++
writing new private key to '70348834.key'
-----
# RSA-1024 no longer meets standards but this is just for testing
$ openssl verify -check_ss_sig -CAfile 70348834.crt 70348834.crt
70348834.crt: OK
$ openssl asn1parse -i <70348834.crt
    0:d=0  hl=4 l= 514 cons: SEQUENCE
    4:d=1  hl=4 l= 363 cons:  SEQUENCE
    8:d=2  hl=2 l=   3 cons:   cont [ 0 ]
   10:d=3  hl=2 l=   1 prim:    INTEGER           :02
   13:d=2  hl=2 l=  20 prim:   INTEGER           :39163AA0A0B6898D0DF0304F4F8D5649507B4877
   35:d=2  hl=2 l=  13 cons:   SEQUENCE
   37:d=3  hl=2 l=   9 prim:    OBJECT            :md5WithRSAEncryption
   48:d=3  hl=2 l=   0 prim:    NULL
   50:d=2  hl=2 l=  19 cons:   SEQUENCE
   52:d=3  hl=2 l=  17 cons:    SET
   54:d=4  hl=2 l=  15 cons:     SEQUENCE
   56:d=5  hl=2 l=   3 prim:      OBJECT            :commonName
   61:d=5  hl=2 l=   8 prim:      UTF8STRING        :70348834
   71:d=2  hl=2 l=  30 cons:   SEQUENCE
   73:d=3  hl=2 l=  13 prim:    UTCTIME           :211217042113Z
   88:d=3  hl=2 l=  13 prim:    UTCTIME           :220116042113Z
  103:d=2  hl=2 l=  19 cons:   SEQUENCE
  105:d=3  hl=2 l=  17 cons:    SET
  107:d=4  hl=2 l=  15 cons:     SEQUENCE
  109:d=5  hl=2 l=   3 prim:      OBJECT            :commonName
  114:d=5  hl=2 l=   8 prim:      UTF8STRING        :70348834
  124:d=2  hl=3 l= 159 cons:   SEQUENCE
  127:d=3  hl=2 l=  13 cons:    SEQUENCE
  129:d=4  hl=2 l=   9 prim:     OBJECT            :rsaEncryption
  140:d=4  hl=2 l=   0 prim:     NULL
  142:d=3  hl=3 l= 141 prim:    BIT STRING
  286:d=2  hl=2 l=  83 cons:   cont [ 3 ]
  288:d=3  hl=2 l=  81 cons:    SEQUENCE
  290:d=4  hl=2 l=  29 cons:     SEQUENCE
  292:d=5  hl=2 l=   3 prim:      OBJECT            :X509v3 Subject Key Identifier
  297:d=5  hl=2 l=  22 prim:      OCTET STRING      [HEX DUMP]:041438C135B9D18DF0668B0AA31933FE0F947FBEDF84
  321:d=4  hl=2 l=  31 cons:     SEQUENCE
  323:d=5  hl=2 l=   3 prim:      OBJECT            :X509v3 Authority Key Identifier
  328:d=5  hl=2 l=  24 prim:      OCTET STRING      [HEX DUMP]:3016801438C135B9D18DF0668B0AA31933FE0F947FBEDF84
  354:d=4  hl=2 l=  15 cons:     SEQUENCE
  356:d=5  hl=2 l=   3 prim:      OBJECT            :X509v3 Basic Constraints
  361:d=5  hl=2 l=   1 prim:      BOOLEAN           :255
  364:d=5  hl=2 l=   5 prim:      OCTET STRING      [HEX DUMP]:30030101FF
  371:d=1  hl=2 l=  13 cons:  SEQUENCE
  373:d=2  hl=2 l=   9 prim:   OBJECT            :md5WithRSAEncryption
  384:d=2  hl=2 l=   0 prim:   NULL
  386:d=1  hl=3 l= 129 prim:  BIT STRING
# the number before the colon on the last line is the offset of the raw signature
$ openssl asn1parse <70348834.crt -strparse 386 -out 70348834.sig
Error in encoding
139775850254976:error:0D07207B:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_get_object:header too long:../crypto/asn1/asn1_lib.c:101:
# ignore that error; RSA signature isn't ASN.1, but -strparse still extracts it, see:
$ ls -l 70348834.sig
-rwxrwxrwx 1 dthomps dthomps 128 Dec 16 23:27 70348834.sig
$ openssl rsautl -verify -certin -inkey 70348834.crt -in 70348834.sig -asn1parse
    0:d=0  hl=2 l=  32 cons: SEQUENCE
    2:d=1  hl=2 l=  12 cons:  SEQUENCE
    4:d=2  hl=2 l=   8 prim:   OBJECT            :md5
   14:d=2  hl=2 l=   0 prim:   NULL
   16:d=1  hl=2 l=  16 prim:  OCTET STRING
      0000 - 2b 7c cf 6d c8 0f 53 82-0b 57 64 4d 5a e0 d6 9a   +|.m..S..WdMZ...
# FYI rsautl -verify isn't properly a verify operation in cryptographic terms,
# technically it's only the 'recover' part of verify-with-recovery (only for RSA)
```

Your 'recovered' signature should look like my last block above except for the data in the OCTET STRING (but it should still be the same length, l=16); if not complain to the cert issuer or provider that they've given you an invalid certificate.

Comment: The result I get is:

# openssl asn1parse -i <CA.crt
Error: offset too large.

I then tried openssl asn1parse -inform der -i <CA.crt
    0:d=0  hl=2 l=  67 prim: ENUMERATED        :657274696669636174653A0A20202020446174613A0A202020202020202056657273696F6E3A20332028307832290A202020202020202053657269616C204E756D6265
   69:d=0  hl=2 l=  58 cons: appl [ 18 ]
   71:d=1  hl=2 l=  48 cons:  EOC
   73:d=2  hl=2 l=  40 cons:   EOC
Error in encoding
140587926308752:error:0D07209B:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_get_object:too long:asn1_lib.c:147:

Comment: Your file apparently contains text before the `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----` line; most `openssl` operations like `verify` ignore that and read only the actual PEM block, but `asn1parse` can't, so you must supply a file containing _only_ the PEM block. A simple way is `openssl x509 <in >out`, or `awk '/-BEGIN/,/-END/' <in >out`, or use any plain-text editor.

Comment: I think you have it. The crt file isn't a real crt file.....its...I don't know. Its not a PEM or P12. But still - you are correct. I will need to remove the chars before the -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- manually

Comment: It clearly _is_ a certificate in PEM format; if it wasn't, `openssl verify` would have given a very different result. PEM format in general does allow other material outside the PEM block, but as I said not `asn1parse` specfically, so yes you must clean-up the file. P12 (PKCS12) is completely different; it is not PEM, and is not a format for a certificate used to verify other entities (except sort-of in Java, not relevant here).